# SQL Server : select max group by where date 2 years ago

Tags: sql, sql-server

For a stored procedure in sql server 2008 management studio i'm trying to build the following:

```
SELECT MAX(Orderdatum) AS Orderdatum, 
       klantnummer 
FROM   Klantenkaart 
GROUP BY klantnummer
```

this gives me the `MAX` orderdatum
but this i want to combine with :
orderdatum < DATEADD(YEAR, -2, SYSDATETIME())

So I want the selection of the records where max(orderdatum) = 2 years ago.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Use `having` with `group by`

```
select MAX(Orderdatum)As Orderdatum, klantnummer from Klantenkaart 
 group by klantnummer
 having orderdatum < DATEADD(YEAR, -2, SYSDATETIME())
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```
SELECT 
 MAX(Orderdatum) AS Orderdatum, 
 klantnummer 
FROM Klantenkaart
 WHERE orderdatum > DATEADD(year,-2,GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY klantnummer
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your condition as a WHERE clause;

```
SELECT MAX(Orderdatum)As Orderdatum, klantnummer 
FROM   Klantenkaart 
WHERE  orderdatum < DATEADD(YEAR, -2, SYSDATETIME())
GROUP BY klantnummer
```